# Missing file in my email when doing resumable upload with gmail api

Tags: api, email, upload, attachment, gmail-api

I'd like to have some help because I'm a bit lost right now.
I'm trying to send attachment with my email through resumable upload. But when I check my email in my inbox, I don't see any file. So I've probably forgot something.

Here's my code. So if someone see something ^^

```
$send_data = 'From: <FROM_EMAIL>' . "\n";
$send_data = 'To: <TO_EMAIL>' . "\n";
$send_data = 'Subject: <SUBJECT>' . "\n";
$send_data = '' . "\n";
$send_data = '<MY MESSAGE>' . "\n";

$send_data= rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($send_data), '+/', '-_'), '=');

$msg = new \Google_Service_Gmail_Mesage();
$msg->setRaw($send_data);

$this->client->setDefer(true);
$request = $this->service->users_messages->send('me', $msg, array('uploadType' => 'resumable'));

$chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
$media = new  \Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
    $this->client,
    $request,
    'message/rfc822',
    null,
    true,
    $chunkSizeBytes
);
$media->setFileSize(filesize(TEST_FILE));

$status = false;
    $handle = fopen(TEST_FILE, "rb");
    $i = 0;
    while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
        $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
        $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
    }
    $result = false;
    if($status != false) {
        $result = $status;
    }
    fclose($handle);
$this->client->setDefer(false);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about gmail api, but I feel like setRaw() will need you to compose the full email (include the attachment) instead just of "body".

Comment: If I include an attachment (base64 encoded) into the email, I'll fall in the file size limit of 5mb (or less).

Comment: This is a tricky part, some service providers count size by original file (i.e. binary), but others count on encoded size (base64, for example).

Comment: (EDIT) I didn't read carefully before posting this comment. Are you sure 5MB is the limitation? It seems to be [25MB](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6584?hl=en) to me.

Comment: Indeed, it' even 35mb when we use resumable upload. But based on my understanding, here's how resumable upload is working : 1) The first request is a normal one, which is limited at 5mb, so, if I add a big attachment, the limit would be reached. 2) The following requests are about the uploading of the files which are cut in multiple chunks. Voila, I don't know if I'm clear enough, but here's how I see it ^^